# WCF/jQuery security

Tags: asp.net, wcf-security

I have a set of WCF services with AspNetCompatibility enabled and consume them from jQuery. My web application requires authentication. Using only logic here (as I lack enough knowledge) does that mean WCF will be accessible and limited only to currently logged users? I know one can catch communication data and try to reuse it later (I don't have ssl) but for that he should be logged in.

Right, wrong or just stupid in my own optimism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you have ASP.NET compatibility enabled and because you're using ASP.NET security, as long as you have the proper `<authorization>` setting for the WCF resource it should be secured by ASP.NET security. At bare minimum this means you should have authorization defined as follows on the WCF resource:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" /> <!-- deny all anonymous users -->
    <allow users="*" /> <!-- allow all authenticated users -->
</authorization>
```

Only if you allowed "*" would your WCF service be inaccessible to non-authenticated users.

You can read more about this [here in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) under the section titled *Hosting WCF Services in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode*.

Comment: That could be a security risk, as you can now use the wcf services without being authenticated. Depending on what they do, that could be a huge risk.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying. I'm not suggesting exactly what the permissions should be, simply giving a basic example of how to secure them with ASP.NET. Certainly you should specify the correct list of users/roles that make sense for your service, using "?" will just prevent the service from being accessed by non-authenticated (anonymous) users.

Comment: your code above would allow anonymous users, not deny them. I think you mean <deny users="?">

Comment: Simon, thanks it's been a while since I messed with authorization section. You are correct, I have the * and ? reversed in my head. I will update my answer.

Comment: you need to reverse the order. the allow * will match before the deny ?

Comment: Ack, yup. Is it obvious yet I don't ever actually mix ASP.NET authorization with my WCF services in my daily practice? ;P If I could give you some of my points I would, but I'll upvote your comments at least. :)